# Create view from parquet unsupported?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a permanent (as non-temporary, not persistent) view from a parquet source:

```
create view foo as select * from parquet.`file:///bar`;
```

and get the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported plan Relation[id#67,col1#68,col2#69,col3#70,col4#71] parquet
```

Creating a temporary view with the same query works just fine. Am I missing something or is this seemingly obvious feature just not implemented yet? I'm running Spark SQL 2.0.0-rc1 (https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/v2.0.0-rc1).